# customizing color tailwind

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I've been reading the documentation for tailwindcss but I just cannot configure my 'tailwind.config.js' file to property export a custom color property to my HTML. Is there something I am doing wrong? I installed the tailwind css 2.0 dependency along with postcss/ autoprefixer. The below are my 3 main files. I am trying to get the custom color name "slightly" to work but just doesn't color up my body background. Wondering if i am exporting my module incorrectly in my JS file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../node_modules/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-slightly-600">
    
    
</body>
</html>


JS:

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      slightly: '#c44e4e'
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

CSS:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: i tried that and its still a white blank screen. do i need to link the tailwind config file to my html file? .. sorry kinda new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include not `tailwind.css` from `node_modules` but compiled files.

Let say you have this basic app structure

```
.
├── resources
│   └── input.css
└── index.html
```

**input.css** - file where you include Tailwind presets

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**tailwind.config.js** - no need to include anywhere. Config file may differ from Tailwind versions (bellow is for v.2.2+ with [jit mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode))

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: {
     content: [
      './**/*.html' // watch all html files
     ],
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      slightly: '#c44e4e'
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Then run next command

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./resources/input.css -o ./public/output.css
```

This command will generate `public/output.css` file which will contain all compiled classes according to your configuration - it should contain `bg-slightly` class

in **index.html** link compiled file from public folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/output.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-slightly">
    
</body>
</html>
```

You can use the `--watch` or `-w` flag to start a watch process and automatically rebuild your CSS any time you make any changes:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./resources/input.css -o ./public/output.css --watch
```

More about Tailwind CLI [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-cli)

Comment: I never knew what CLI was until now.. LOL. thank you Ihar .. wondering as a beginner how would i decipher documentation like that? I find documentations from React and Tailwind isn't as straightforward as people say they are.. even though React is considered to having the best documentation around.. im usually lost

Comment: I'm not using Tailwind CLI mostly, I'm handling it with poctcss but it can be very helpful)

Comment: by the way it seems like the CLI way of tailwind isn't using the @tailwind imports from my styles.css.. even though the documentation mentions that I should have that file. That is why I am confused.. it mentions to have a customized css file with all 3 imports but doesnt use it?

Answer (score 0):

The route cause here may be that you are trying to reference a shade of your custom color that does not exist (ie: `slightly-600`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>
<body class="bg-slightly-600"> # here you are trying to insert the   color `slightly` with shade `600`
    
    
</body>
</html>


JS:

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      slightly: '#c44e4e' # but down here, you aren't defining the  shade `600` for slightly
    },
...
```

So you can do one of two things:

1. Define the shade `600` for `slightly` in your `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      slightly: {
        DEFAULT: '#c44e4e',
        600: # whatever your custom shade is here!
    },
...
```

or
2. Keep the config the same, but change the reference in your HTML such that you are referencing your base color, and not the shade `600`

```html
...
<body class="bg-slightly"> # no reference to 600
...
```

You could verify that this color shade does/does not exist by searching the `main.css` file that is generated by tailwinds and searching for keyword `slightly-600`. If you didn't define the shade of a custom color explicitly, it will not be generated.